# Do I need to Declare a Variable to be used in a bind_result() Statement?

Tags: php, mysqli, intelephense

When writing prepared statement and binding the results using a `bind_result()` statement ([referenced here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php#example-1357)), considering the example below, do I need to declare `$a`, `$b` or `$c` before it's bound in the statement?

```
$a = ""; //does this declaration need to happen?

$stmtGetData = $conn1->prepare("SELECT a, b, c FROM myTable");
$stmtGetData->execute();
$stmtGetData->bind_result($a, $b, $c);
$stmtGetData->fetch();
$stmtGetData->close();
```

The code seems to work either way whether or not the variables are declared before the `bind_result()`. While the PHP documentation referenced above does not show the variables being declared, Intelephense shows an `Undefined variable` exception if they are not.

My impression is that Intelephense is just not picking up on the fact that this is 'okay', but I want to make sure that I am doing this the correct way.

Comment: Yes, it's OK. Using the variable in a reference parameter automatically creates it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might not be easy to understand, but when you pass variables by reference to `bind_result()` you are actually defining them. You don't need to declare them before.

You can easily test this assumption:

```
function test(mysqli $conn1){
    $a = ""; //does this declaration need to happen?

    $stmtGetData = $conn1->prepare("SELECT 1,2,3");
    $stmtGetData->execute();
    $stmtGetData->bind_result($a, $b, $c);

    var_dump($a, $b, $c);
}

test($mysqli);
// Outputs the following with no warnings about undefined variables
// string(0) ""
// NULL
// NULL
```

If the variables `$b` and `$c` were undefined, you would [get a warning](https://3v4l.org/PMp8i) when trying to use it `var_dump`.

[Demo online.](https://phpize.online/?phpses=63e9672ed9e68412f053c597054e6598&sqlses=null&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57)

There could be a couple of reasons why Intelephense tells you these variables are undefined:

1. You didn't specify `mysqli` correctly as the parameter type. Check the namespace or always use a fully qualified name.
2. You misspelt the `mysqli` object variable name. Is it really `$conn1` in your current scope?
3. You are using a very old Intelephense version. There was a problem with this situation in a very old version. Check for updates.

Comment: This doesn't show anything because var_dump will define any variables passed to it even if they didn't appear in bind_result()

Comment: @jmc I beg to differ. https://3v4l.org/PMp8i You can clearly see the warning produced as the variable does not exist.